# How to get specific class within inner html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to access a specific class name and click on it within another class.
How would I go by doing this?

For example,

```
var keyword = "blah";
//Add elements with this specific class name to array
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    array[i] = documents.getElementsByClassName(specific string)[i].innerHTML

//Once a specific element in the array has a matching keyword get specific class name of that element and click on it
for(var j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    if(array[j].match(keyword) == keyword){
        //Get class name within the innerhtml and click on it
```

Comment: Why can't you use the [jQuery click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)? Specify class name as selector, such as $('.blah')

Comment: @JL Okay lets say theres multiple keywords that says blah in the array. How would I click the blah that is inside that specific innerhtml?

Comment: Is it right that you want to trigger a click event on an element which contains a string (e.g. 'blah') as innerhtml but has a unknown classname?

Comment: @AlexanderScholz I get all the classes that have  a specific string and add them to array. Then the specific class that has the matching keyword called blah. I wanna click another specific class inside that class.

Comment: So it's `$('.blah .specific-child').trigger('click')`?

Comment: @AlexanderScholz   See I would rather use that array. Because when I use window.alert(array[j]) after the .match it gives me the correct class. I just want to access whats inside that array at index j which is a specific class name

Answer (score 0):

As J L said, the easiest way by far is to use jQuery .click() with an appropriate locator.  Check out: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

You might also want to use [contains](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) or [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) features

Comment: How would I use the click method using my array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to add an event on a click for elements with a matching keyword :

```
var keyword = ".blah";
$(keyword).click( function() {

    console.log( $(this).attr('class') );
});
```

You can also trigger the event associated with a click on elements with a matching keyword :

```
var keyword = ".blah";
$(keyword).trigger( 'click' );
```

**Additionally**, you can filter keyword-matching elements within a group of elements of a certain class :

```
var keyword = ".blah";
$('.className').filter(keyword).click( function() {

    console.log( $(this).attr('class') );
});
```

or

```
var keyword = ".blah";
$('.className').filter(keyword).trigger( 'click' );
```